# using jquery to create navigation system

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I am trying to create a menu system where when a list anchor is clicked, a div below the ul list is shown. but the system is not working and i can't control if the user is over the displayed div. 
Here below is the code where

- I created UL list to create tabs
- I created DIVs as pages to be displayed
- I created jquery mouseenter event to display the div with same class as of the link's ID
- I used mouseleave function to hide the displayed div.

  ```
   <style>
   .tabs_button ul {list-style:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
   .tabs_button ul li {float:left; display:inline; margin-right:50px;}
  .tabs_button ul li a{color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;}
   .tabs_button ul li a:hover{color:#FFC222;}
    .tab_pages{clear:both; position:absolute; }
      .tab_pages div{display:none;width:200px; height:200px; background-           color:#CCC;margin-top:30px;}
   </style>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(e) {
      $(".tabs_button a").mouseenter(function(e) {
      var tid=this.id;
  $(".tab_pages div").hide();
           $(".tab_pages ."+tid).show();
           });
         $(".tabs_button a").mouseleave(function(e) {
  var tid=this.id;
          $(".tab_pages ."+tid).hide();
           });

           });
         </script>
      <div class="tabs_button">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#" id="page1">Cars</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" id="page2">Price & Offers</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" id="page3">Chevy Experience</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" id="page4">Service</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" id="page5">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
       <div class="tab_pages">
       <div class="page1">
       Cars Display Page
        </div>
          <div class="page2">
           Offers Display Page
           </div>
          <div class="page3">
          Chevy Exp Page
           </div>
           <div class="page4">
          Service Display Page
           </div>
            <div class="page5">
           Contact us Display Page
           </div>
             </div>
  ```

Here the main part i am having problem is to keep div showing if the user is hovering over the div.

Edit: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VVPtX/6/)

Comment: You say "when a list anchor is clicked", but your code is for mouse over events. If you want it on click, you'll have to use the `.click()` jquery method. If you just want it to show on hover, I would suggest using :hover in css instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created complete code bin for above issue on http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpam
So, Try on it.

To Solve this follow below steps:

1) Include latest jQuery.js javascript file on html header tag first.

2) HTML (Little bit Changes)

```
<div class="tabs_button">
  <ul>
    <li id="page1">
      <a href="#">
        Cars
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="page2">
      <a href="#">
        Price &amp; Offers
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="page3">
      <a href="#">
        Chevy Experience
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="page4">
      <a href="#">
        Service
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="page5">
      <a href="#">
        Contact Us
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab_pages">
  <div class="page1">
    Cars Display Page
  </div>

  <div class="page2">
    Offers Display Page
  </div>

  <div class="page3">
    Chevy Exp Page
  </div>
  <div class="page4">
    Service Display Page
  </div>
  <div class="page5">
    Contact us Display Page
  </div>
</div>
```

3) CSS (Add Few More Styles):

```
body{
  background-color:#000;
}
.tabs_button{
  width:950px;
}
.tabs_button ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;

}
.tabs_button ul li {
  width:120px;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:10px;
  text-align:center:

}
.tabs_button ul li:hover a{
  color:#FFC222;
}
.tabs_button ul li:hover{
  background-color:#445566;
}
.tabs_button ul li a{
  color:#FFF;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.tabs_button ul li a:hover{
  color:#FFC222;
}
.tabs_button ul li.selected a{
  color:#FFC222;
}
.tabs_button ul li.selected{
  background-color:#445566;
}
.tab_pages{
  clear:both;
  position:absolute;
}
.tab_pages div{
  display:none;
  width:120px;
  height:200px;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#445566;
  margin-top:27px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

4) JQuery for Menu Navigation:

```
$(".tabs_button li,.tab_pages div").mouseenter(function() {
    var className = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".tabs_button #" + className).removeClass("selected");
    if (typeof(className) == "undefined" || className == null) {
        className = $(this).attr('class');
        $(".tabs_button li").removeClass("selected");
        $(".tabs_button #" + className).addClass("selected");
    }

    $(".tab_pages div").hide();
    var offset = $(".tabs_button li#" + className).offset();
    $(".tab_pages ." + className).css({
        'left': offset.left - 8
    });
    $(".tab_pages ." + className).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the mousover event instead, like:

```
    $(".tabs_button a,.tab_pages").mouseover(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the (".tab_pages div").hide(); from your mouseenter() event. Also, in the .tab_pages style, change position:absolute to float:left. If you were to use absolute positioning, you would need to specify either a top or bottom position and a left or right position, for example - top:0px; left:0px. But since you are specifying a top-margin of 30px, use float - absolutely positioned divs cannot have margins added to them. Lastly, in your .tabs_button ul li style, the display:inline does not do anything - calling float:left changes the li to a block element - which is what you want. I have copied the code with the changes below - should work for you.

```
 <style>
    .tabs_button ul {list-style:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
    .tabs_button ul li {float:left; margin-right:50px;}
    .tabs_button ul li a{color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;}
    .tabs_button ul li a:hover{color:#FFC222;}
    .tab_pages{clear: both; float: left; }
    .tab_pages div{display:none;width:200px; height:200px; background-color:#CCC;margin-top:30px;}
 </style>

 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $(".tabs_button a").mouseover(function(e) {
            var tid=this.id;
            $(".tab_pages ."+tid).stop().show();
         });


       $(".tabs_button a").mouseout(function(e) {
        var tid=this.id;
            $(".tab_pages ."+tid).stop().hide();
         });

         });
       </script>
       <body>
    <div class="tabs_button">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#" id="page1">Cars</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="page2">Price &amp; Offers</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="page3">Chevy Experience</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="page4">Service</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="page5">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

     <div class="tab_pages">
     <div class="page1">
        Cars Display Page
      </div>

      <div class="page2">
         Offers Display Page
      </div>

        <div class="page3">
        Chevy Exp Page
         </div>
         <div class="page4">
        Service Display Page
         </div>
          <div class="page5">
         Contact us Display Page
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, just realized I changed your mouseenter() mouseleave() to mouseover() mouseout(). Should work with either. Sorry.